# Laravel hasManyThrough and lazy eager loading

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following models set up in Laravel 5 (everything is namespaced into `App\Models`, but I've removed that for readability) :

```
class Client extends Model {
    public function templates() { return $this->hasMany('Template'); }
    public function documents() { return $this->hasManyThrough('Template', 'Document'); }
    public function users() { return $this->hasMany('User'); }
}

class Template extends Model {
    public function client() { return $this->belongsTo('Client'); }
    public function documents() { return $this->hasMany('Document'); }
}

class Document extends Model {
    public function template() { return $this->belongsTo('Template'); }
}
```

In a controller, I have the current user:

```
$user = \Auth::user();
$client = $user->client;
```

I want to show a list of

- the templates for a client
- the documents for a client, separately, not grouped by template

It seems easy enough; I already have both of the relations needed. The question is, if I lazy eager load `templates` and `documents` onto `$client`, do I still need to eager load `templates.documents` (hasManyThrough) or is Laravel smart enough to realise?

```
$client->load( 'templates', 'documents' );
// or...
$client->load( 'templates', 'templates.documents' );
// or...
$client->load( 'templates', 'documents', 'templates.documents' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found that it's [possible to see if a relation is loaded](http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/check-if-relations-are-loaded-on-eloquent-model), so I've run `artisan tinker` and tested:

```
$c = Client::first();
array_key_exists('documents', $c->getRelations()); // false

// Loading `templates` and `documents` separately doesn't load `templates.documents`
$c = Client::first();
$c->load('templates', 'documents');
array_key_exists('documents', $c->getRelations()); // true
array_key_exists('documents', $c->templates->first()->getRelations()); // false

// Loading `documents.templates` doesn't load `documents` or `templates`
$c = Client::first();
$c->load('templates.documents');
array_key_exists('documents', $c->templates->first()->getRelations()); // true
array_key_exists('documents', $c->getRelations()); // false
```

So I guess the definitive answer is that if you have a `hasManyThrough` you **must explicitly load any relation you'll access** - it's not smart enough to realise that it's already loaded the relation for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$client->load( 'templates', 'documents' );
```

Should be fine. `hasManyThrough` is just a shortcut - laravel will try to get `documents` from `client`.

You can always check it yourself - run both, and compare results.

Comment: I'm interested that you changed your answer; did you benchmark it yourself, and if so, did you use an online bencher? I'm just asking because I'm not aware of any for L5

Comment: Actually I wanted to delete it as I read your question incorrectly (I read `hasManyThrough` as `hasMany`). I do not think that there is any significant difference as Laravel's documentation states that it is a shortcut. I did not benchmark it.

Comment: Not tested on `hasManyThrough` but it should work the same:  if you load `'templates', 'documents'` you can access them by `$client->documents; $client->templates`. If you load `'templates.documents'` you can access them by `$client->templates->documents`